# HTML iframe audio file background

Tags: html, iframe

On a project, i have an iframe and a link targeting it. The link leads to an mp3 file. However on google chrome, and maybe other browsers, the iframe appears with a horrible black background.

Is there any way to fix this?
All solutions i have found so far talk about changing the background in the source file, but this is not possible for me as it is an mp3 file not an html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have zero control over the default presentation of an audio player when you link to it in this way.  In fact, it's very common that the file will just be downloaded instead of played in a browser.

If you want to control it, you need to build an HTML page that loads the audio file.

Comment: Thanks, i had hoped i could do it, but i will have to make a page i think

Comment: @HCook Yes, you will.  This page doesn't have to be difficult... Just pass the URL to the audio file in the anchor fragment, and on page load, have it set the `src` on an `<audio>` element.